# Case studies on community capacity to use or create open data?

Tags: education

I'm looking for detailed and *objective* accounts of projects etc, that include coverage of the skills and capacities of individuals and community organisations to harness open data. I am interested more in discussions around specific technical and practical skills rather than more nebulous political or institutional issues.

These might be academic papers, organisational reports or longform blog posts.

This is the *kind* of thing I'm looking for, though accounts of specific projects would also be great:

```
Johnson, M. P. (2014). Data, Analytics and Community‐Based Organizations: Transforming Data to Decisions for Community Development. I/S: A Journal of Law and Policy for the Information Society, 11(1), 49–96. Retrieved from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263200235_Data_Analytics_and_Community-Based_Organizations_Transforming_Data_to_Decisions_for_Community_Development
```

Answer (score 2):

you might consider cross-posting your question here: https://discuss.okfn.org/c/policy-research